# How to make margin: 0px auto work for container wrapped around floating divs

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a container (#out) wrapping one container (#inner) which itself hosts some containers (#innest) that are floating.

Why does margin: 0px auto ONLY center the container #inner, if I specify a width and how can I avoid that? I the number of .innest may differ, so I cannot set a fixed width for #inner.

http://jsfiddle.net/dyyes/  => not working
http://jsfiddle.net/dyyes/1/ => working with a fixed width

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Without giving `inner` a width it will only expand as much content is in.

Answer (score 0):

use `text-align:center;` like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dyyes/6/)

Comment: very good idea, but I have another constraint I forgot to mention:

#out must not be catching click events, so it has to have height: 0px

Comment: @Pat, what's your constraint? I was about to mention the same thing; `text-align:center;` on the outer div, and `text-align:left;` on the inner div. If the *only* content of the outer div is the inner div, I don't see the pitfall here

Comment: There are elements on a lower z-index level that may be a "click-target" that are cover by #out

Answer (score 0):

Check the fiddle its working:

http://jsfiddle.net/dyyes/8/

```
#inner
{
    text-align:center;    
    border: 1px solid #C00;
}
.innest{
    display: inline-block;
}
```